# Object created has the wrong information after being created

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, minecraft

I'm trying to create a new object and pass some variables to it. However when I get the variables from the new object right after it has been created, the variables are different than what was in the method.

This is how I create a new "Region" object.

```
    public void createRegionObject(String world, Location min, Location max, String name) {
    if(regions.containsKey(name)) {
        Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("Overwriting " + name);
    }
    
    //Debugging: 
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("-------------------");
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("Info used to create new object:");
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("Name: " + name);
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("World: " + world);
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("Loc1: " + min.getX() + ", " + min.getY() + ", " + min.getZ());
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("Loc2: " + max.getX() + ", " + max.getY() + ", " + max.getZ());
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("-------------------");
    
    regions.put(name, new Region(world, min, max, name));
}
```

And this is the constructor for that object:

```
public Region(String world, Location min, Location max, String name) {
    this.world = world;
    this.loc1 = min;
    this.loc2 = max;
    this.name = name;
    
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("-------------------");
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("Info inside of object: ");
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("Name: " + name);
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("World: " + world);
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("Loc1: " + loc1.getX() + ", " + loc1.getY() + ", " + loc1.getZ());
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("Loc2: " + loc2.getX() + ", " + loc2.getY() + ", " + loc2.getZ());
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("-------------------");
}
```

Finally, this is the console output. How are the input and output different from each other? (Specifically, look at the z-axes of Loc1 and Loc2.)

```
[22:04:03 INFO]: -------------------
[22:04:03 INFO]: Info used to create new object:
[22:04:03 INFO]: Name: test
[22:04:03 INFO]: World: test
[22:04:03 INFO]: Loc1: -236.0, 64.0, -47.0
[22:04:03 INFO]: Loc2: -238.0, 64.0, -45.0
[22:04:03 INFO]: -------------------
[22:04:03 INFO]: -------------------
[22:04:03 INFO]: Info inside of object: 
[22:04:03 INFO]: Name: test
[22:04:03 INFO]: World: test
[22:04:03 INFO]: Loc1: -236.0, 64.0, -51.0
[22:04:03 INFO]: Loc2: -238.0, 64.0, -49.0
[22:04:03 INFO]: -------------------
```

Comment: which library are you using the location from ? also show how you are using values to create the region object ?

Comment: Does this happen every time, or do they sometimes match? Are any other components of Location ever different? Could the original Location object be being updated in another thread?

Comment: Try putting a logging statement in Location.setZ(...) so you can see when it changes

Comment: Thanks for your responses. 

I’m using Bukkits location which represents a point in a minecraft world. 

This happens every time in my testing (over 20 times tested tweaking different things). I’ll triple check everything that modifies the HashMap, I’ll also try to log the set Z to make sure it only changes once.

Comment: Where do the original Location objects come from? If you are storing references to objects which are known to the rest of Minecraft, they might be changed by some other thread. You could make a 'defensive copy' of each Location at the start of `createRegionObject` to ensure that no-one else can change them. For instance, lets say that you get your max location from the sheep that is furthest away from your player. That location may be part of the sheep and may be updated as the sheep moves (I don't know Minecraft internals well, that's just a possible example of what could be happening)